# Custom UITableCellView user interaction

Tags: ios, uitableview, interaction

I created a Custom UITableCellView for my application. Each cell has two buttons. The problem I am facing is that the cell itself is selectable which leads to a confused user and poor design. How do I disable the interaction for the cell but keep the interaction enabled for the UIButtons in the cell?

Thanks!
Satyam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` and be sure to keep your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` unimplemented. That means that your cells will not be interactive, but you can still get messages from your buttons.

Apart from that, of course I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but remember that you can use a UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton as an accessory view, which is a different "button" from the cell itself. More info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1).